# Need explanation on flask.request

Tags: python, flask

I am using the flask micro-framework and need some explanation on the `flask.request`. The documentation on the [The request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/reqcontext/#diving-into-context-locals) is not clear to me. As I tried:

```
from flask import request
help(request)
```

which returns `Help on LocalProxy in module werkzeug.local object` and `dir(request)`
returns an empty list.What methods I can access using a dot on  `request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flask `request` global is a proxy object for a *request context*; the proxy accesses the correct context to keep your request data access thread safe.

See the [Request Context documentation](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqcontext/).

For documentation on what is available, you can read the [`flask.Request` API documentation](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Request), and the [Werkzeug documentation on Request / Response objects](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/).

In an interactive session, import `flask.wrappers.Request`:

```
>>> from flask.wrappers import Request
>>> Request
<class 'flask.wrappers.Request'>
>>> help(Request)
Help on class Request in module flask.wrappers:
[ ... etc ...]
```